# How can i get value one by one on click from loop in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually, I make a `for loop` its working fine but now I want to get loop values one by one on button click but I'm not able to get. What is wrong in it?

When I click on button then I get direct 10 but I want to get one by one like if I click on button first time then it will be 2 when I click then it will be 3.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
var i;
$('button').click(function(){
         for( i=1; i<=10; i++)
             $(this).text(i);
     });
    alert(i);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
```

The answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purpose of `for loop` is different than your use case . You have to increment single variable at each click and show inside button.

```js
var i =1;
$('#button').click(function(){
   if(i<10)i++;
   $(this).attr('value',i); 
});
// This is how you could have acheived through loop , but not recommended because of extra memory and calculation.
var k =1;
$('#loopbutton').click(function(){
   k++;
   for(j=1;(j<=k && j<=10);j++){
    $(this).attr('value',j); 
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="button" value="1" />
<h3>Now Using For loop</h3>
<input type="button" id="loopbutton" value="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks @manikant gautam it working fine, Great idea with for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `for` loop for that (unless you `await` constructed `Promises`, which is a bit convoluted) - rather, just increment and alert `i` on every handler call, until the 10th:

```js
let i = 2;
$('button').click(function() {
  if (i <= 10) {
    console.log(i);
    $(this).text(i);
    i++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
```

The `Promise` way in a `for` loop, if you're curious:

```js
const button = $('button');
let i = 2;
const resolves = [];
const promises = Array.from(
  { length: 10 },
  (_, i) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolves.push(resolve);
  })
);
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    await promises[i];
    button.text(i + 2);
  }
})();

button.on('click', () => {
  if (resolves.length) resolves.shift()();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the entire loop on each button click. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $('button').click(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).text(i);
    alert(i);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#AddButton').click( function()
{
    var input = $('#TextBox');
    input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 1);
    if(input.val()>=10){
    alert("this is last limit");
    input.val(0) ;
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="TextBox" id="TextBox" value="0" />
<input type="Button" id='AddButton' value="+" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can do like this way also

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use the commented out statement instead if you don't wish to stop at 10.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 1;
 $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).text(i<10?++i:i);
  //$(this).text(++i);
 });
});
```